# CNN model for RGB images giving 0% accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I am trying to train a CNN model on CelebA (RGB images) dataset. But, when I train the model and check its accuracy it is 0% or close to 0%. I think the issue is in the ***ConNeuralNet*** function or the *hyperparameters* but due to my limited knowledge I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can someone please help. Thanks

```py
# Creating a simple network
class ConvNeuralNet(torch.nn.Module):          
 
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10178):     
        super(ConvNeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layer1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv_layer2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.max_pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)
    
        self.conv_layer3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv_layer4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.max_pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)
    
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(13312, 128)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv_layer1(x)
        out = self.conv_layer2(out)
        out = self.max_pool1(out)
    
        out = self.conv_layer3(out)
        out = self.conv_layer4(out)
        out = self.max_pool2(out)
            
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
    
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return F.log_softmax(out,dim=-1)

def trainTorch(torch_model, train_loader, test_loader,
    nb_epochs=NB_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, train_end=-1, test_end=-1, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, optimizer=None):

    train_loss = []
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    step = 0
    for _epoch in range(nb_epochs):
      for xs, ys in train_loader:
        xs, ys = Variable(xs), Variable(ys)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
          xs, ys = xs.cuda(), ys.cuda()
      
      
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        preds = torch_model(xs)
        preds = F.log_softmax(preds, dim=1)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(preds, ys)
        loss.backward()
        train_loss.append(loss.data.item())
        optimizer.step()  # update gradients

        preds_np = preds.cpu().detach().numpy()
        correct += (np.argmax(preds_np, axis=1) == ys.cpu().detach().numpy()).sum()
        total += train_loader.batch_size
        step += 1
        if total % 1000 == 0:
          acc = float(correct) / total
          print('[%s] Training accuracy: %.2f%%' % (step, acc * 100))
          total = 0
          correct = 0


nb_epochs = 8
image_size = 64
batch_size = 64
num_classes = 10178
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 8
# Device will determine whether to run the training on GPU or CPU.
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(image_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])


train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.CelebA('data', split='train', target_type='identity', transform=trans,     download="True"),
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.CelebA('data', split='test', target_type='identity', transform=trans),
    batch_size=batch_size)


#Training the model
print("Training Model")
# Set optimizer with optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model1.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay =     0.005, momentum = 0.9)
total_step = len(train_loader)
trainTorch(model1, train_loader, test_loader, nb_epochs, batch_size, train_end, test_end, learning_rate, optimizer = optimizer)
```

Comment: What does your model output? is it logits? class probabilities?

Comment: Note that `F.log_softmax(preds, dim=1)` isn't doing anything since you don't assign the return value.

Comment: hey @Dr.Snoopy, I have added that code. Sorry I forgot to add that earlier.

Comment: @jodag, you are right about that. But, it does not solves the problem. It was returning the to the preds variable, I forgot to revert that.

Comment: You should replace `F.nll_loss(preds, ys)` with `F.cross_entropy(preds, ys)` which is mathematically equivalent to `F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(preds), ys))`. You shouldn't be providing raw logits to `F.nll_loss` since it expects the inputs to be log-probabilities.

Comment: You did not apply a softmax activation to the predictions (your model predicts logits), so everything after making a prediction is wrong.

Comment: Couple of extra points: 1. you have no activation functions in your conv layers, 2. your conditional for checking accuracy should probably be once per epoch, or at least `if total > 1000:` (I assume you meant `step` here instead), 3. @jodag's point above, the loss should be on the log softmax return value, not on the raw logits, 4. Look at [adaptive pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html) for your last pooling layer so that you don't have such a large linear layer.

Comment: @jodag, I have added `loss = F.cross_entropy(preds, ys)` , but it still didn't improved the accuracy. As suggested in other comments there are still somethings missing. I am working on that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I have added the softmax activation in `ConvNeuralNet > forward` like `return F.log_softmax(out,dim=-1)` and `preds = F.log_softmax(preds, dim=1)` in `trainTorch` function, but it still does not work. I have updated the code in the question. Can you please look at again? Thanks!

Comment: Softmax and log_softmax are not the same thing, you did not add a softmax activation actually.

Comment: Ohh, my bad then. Can you please guide me how and where exactly should I add 'softmax'?

Answer (score 1):

**Update I ran the code for a bit to see if it would start converging. One thing is that there are over 10,000 classes. With a batch size of 64 this means that it will take more than 150 mini-batches before your model has seen every class in your dataset. You certanly shouldn't expect the model to start achieving accurate predictions within a few hundred steps.

When I printed the loss value I noticed it was decreasing very slowly. I changed to learning rate to `0.01` and it started decreasing faster.

Also, your model is very shallow for a face recognition model. You're better off using something like a resnet variant (e.g. resnet-50 or resnet-101 from torchvision), rather than custom rolling your own model.

Primary changes include

- Learning rate increased
- Fix the loss function
- Remove log_softmax from output of model
- Add activation to the conv layers

IMO the comments about softmax are a bit misleading since you don't need to softmax the output of your model if you are using `cross_entropy`. You also don't need `softmax` to get the `argmax` of the prediction since both `softmax` and `log_softmax` don't change the relative ordering of the predictions (i.e. both `softmax` and `log` are strictly increasing functions).

IMO the comment about using average pooling to reduce the input size of the first fc layer is a good one and may improve performance, but you'll need to experiment with that one to find good parameters for it so I left it out of this answer.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

# Creating a simple network
class ConvNeuralNet(torch.nn.Module):          
 
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10178):     
        super(ConvNeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layer1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv_layer2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.max_pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)
    
        self.conv_layer3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv_layer4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.max_pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)
    
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(13312, 128)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # note the relu activations on the conv layers
        out = F.relu(self.conv_layer1(x))
        out = F.relu(self.conv_layer2(out))
        out = self.max_pool1(out)
    
        out = F.relu(self.conv_layer3(out))
        out = F.relu(self.conv_layer4(out))
        out = self.max_pool2(out)
        
        # you may want an adaptive average pool 2d here to reduce size of feature map further

        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
    
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        # return raw logits, not log-softmax output
        return out

def trainTorch(torch_model, train_loader, test_loader, nb_epochs, batch_size, learning_rate, optimizer):

    train_loss = []
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    step = 0
    for _epoch in range(nb_epochs):
      for xs, ys in train_loader:
        # the Variable interface has been deprecated for years, it is effectively a no-op in modern pytorch
        # see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
          xs, ys = xs.cuda(), ys.cuda()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        logits = torch_model(xs)
        # don't softmax or log-softmax the inputs to cross_entropy
        loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, ys)
        # The following is equivalent but less numerically stable
        # loss = F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(logits), ys)
        loss.backward()
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.step()  # update gradients

        logits_np = logits.cpu().detach().numpy()
        correct += (np.argmax(logits_np, axis=1) == ys.cpu().detach().numpy()).sum()
        total += train_loader.batch_size
        step += 1
        if step % 200 == 0:
          acc = float(correct) / total
          avg_loss = sum(train_loss) / len(train_loss)
          print(f'[{step}] Training accuracy: {acc*100:.2f}%     Training loss: {avg_loss:.4f}')
          total = 0
          correct = 0
          train_loss = []


nb_epochs = 8
image_size = 64
batch_size = 64
num_classes = 10178
# increased learning rate to 0.01
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 8
# Device will determine whether to run the training on GPU or CPU.
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(image_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.CelebA('data', split='train', target_type='identity', transform=trans, download=True),
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.CelebA('data', split='test', target_type='identity', transform=trans),
    batch_size=batch_size)

model = ConvNeuralNet(num_classes)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()

#Training the model
print("Training Model")
# Set optimizer with optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=0.005, momentum=0.9)
total_step = len(train_loader)
trainTorch(model, train_loader, test_loader, nb_epochs, batch_size, learning_rate, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Output

```bash
Training Model
[200] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.2286
[400] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.2286
[600] Training accuracy: 0.04%     Training loss: 9.2265
[800] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.2253
[1000] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.2222
[1200] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.2105
[1400] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.1776
[1600] Training accuracy: 0.03%     Training loss: 9.1329
[1800] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.1013
[2000] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0830
[2200] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0715
[2400] Training accuracy: 0.01%     Training loss: 9.0622
[2600] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0456
[2800] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.0301
[3000] Training accuracy: 0.00%     Training loss: 9.0357
[3200] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0402
[3400] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0321
[3600] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 9.0217
[3800] Training accuracy: 0.02%     Training loss: 8.9757
[4000] Training accuracy: 0.09%     Training loss: 8.9059
[4200] Training accuracy: 0.09%     Training loss: 8.8331
[4400] Training accuracy: 0.09%     Training loss: 8.7601
[4600] Training accuracy: 0.09%     Training loss: 8.7356
[4800] Training accuracy: 0.10%     Training loss: 8.6717
[5000] Training accuracy: 0.12%     Training loss: 8.6311
[5200] Training accuracy: 0.16%     Training loss: 8.5515
[5400] Training accuracy: 0.16%     Training loss: 8.4943
[5600] Training accuracy: 0.14%     Training loss: 8.4345
[5800] Training accuracy: 0.14%     Training loss: 8.4107
[6000] Training accuracy: 0.18%     Training loss: 8.3317
[6200] Training accuracy: 0.22%     Training loss: 8.2716
[6400] Training accuracy: 0.31%     Training loss: 8.1934
[6600] Training accuracy: 0.30%     Training loss: 8.1500
[6800] Training accuracy: 0.35%     Training loss: 8.0979
[7000] Training accuracy: 0.21%     Training loss: 8.0739
[7200] Training accuracy: 0.44%     Training loss: 8.0220
[7400] Training accuracy: 0.29%     Training loss: 7.9819
```

From the output we see the loss is decreasing and the accuracy is starting to increase. Its hard to predict how well this will work and when it will converge but this is a good start. You'll probably need to use a better model and a learning rate scheduler to get better performance.

For example, just switching for a resnet-50

```py
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
model.fc = nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, num_classes)
```

The model starts converging much faster

```
Training Model
[200] Training accuracy: 0.05%     Training loss: 9.1942
[400] Training accuracy: 0.05%     Training loss: 8.9244
[600] Training accuracy: 0.15%     Training loss: 8.5936
[800] Training accuracy: 0.30%     Training loss: 8.3147
[1000] Training accuracy: 0.39%     Training loss: 8.0745
[1200] Training accuracy: 0.43%     Training loss: 7.9146
[1400] Training accuracy: 0.45%     Training loss: 7.7706
[1600] Training accuracy: 0.64%     Training loss: 7.6551
[1800] Training accuracy: 0.68%     Training loss: 7.5784
[2000] Training accuracy: 0.74%     Training loss: 7.5327
[2200] Training accuracy: 0.72%     Training loss: 7.4689
[2400] Training accuracy: 0.63%     Training loss: 7.4378
[2600] Training accuracy: 0.83%     Training loss: 7.3789
[2800] Training accuracy: 0.90%     Training loss: 7.2812
[3000] Training accuracy: 0.84%     Training loss: 7.2771
[3200] Training accuracy: 0.96%     Training loss: 7.2536
[3400] Training accuracy: 1.00%     Training loss: 7.2538
```

Comment: I've used your changes but unfortunately, the training is still the same. I get the below ouput..
```Training Model
[125] Training accuracy: 0.01%
[250] Training accuracy: 0.01%
[375] Training accuracy: 0.00%
[500] Training accuracy: 0.03%
[625] Training accuracy: 0.01%
[750] Training accuracy: 0.04%
[875] Training accuracy: 0.00%
[1000] Training accuracy: 0.01%... ```

Comment: One thing though, I remember when I first started this it was giving me `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x13312 and 1600x128)` error. So, I manually updated the layer (`self.fc1 = nn.Linear(13312, 128)`) to that size and the error was gone. I don't know if this is causing this whole mess or not.

Comment: Updated, hopefully this helps. You basically just need a higher learning rate and patience. Other things would be needed to make this a good face recognition model but this should be a good start.

Comment: Hey @jodag, I have tested the updated code with and without the resnet. Without the Resnet the output is almost same as yours. But, the average accuracy still is around 0%. In case of Resnet I got the following output with average accuracy of 1.5% approx and it took more than 24 hours to just train the dataset. 


    [125] Training accuracy: 0.06%
    [250] Training accuracy: 0.06%
    [375] Training accuracy: 0.07%
    [500] Training accuracy: 0.12%
    [625] Training accuracy: 0.22%
    .
    .

    [20125] Training accuracy: 3.16%
    [20250] Training accuracy: 2.77%

Comment: Point is, previously I was getting around 98% accuracy in case of MNIST dataset and the model was LeNet5 in this same code. I changed the model and some other features in the code to work it on celebA dataset and get same(or at least improving) accuracy but it does not seem to work.

Comment: MNIST is completely trivial when compared to face classification. Consider that MNIST has 10 classes so a random model will get 10% accuracy on that dataset. CelebA has over 10,000 classes (one for each person in the dataset) so a random model will get 0.01% accuracy.

Comment: Changing the model alone is not sufficient to achieve high performance. Resnet should improve things but you'll need to improve the optimization loop using either a learning rate scheduler or an alternative optimizer (like Adam). There are high performing face recognition systems out there that you can look at. For example https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/recognition/arcface_torch is effectively the SOTA system at the moment (trained on a dataset with over 2 million subjects). Also note it took about 190 hours to train on an 8-GPU server.